# Symfony with API Platform + Form and controller

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I have started a Symfony 6 project using the classic `RegitrationController` (that inherits from `AbstractController`), `RegistrationFormType` and `User` entity obtained from:

```
symfony console make:registration-form
```

I can now create a user through the form that adds a new entity in my database.

I also wanted to create an API using **API Plateform**. I have then added a couple modifications to my `User` schema and the API is working, I can create a user through the API too.

I now wonder how to properly couple the form/controller and the API. Indeed, in order not to have redondant code and use the same `User` schema, I would like to find a way that my `RegistrationFormType` works with the API. Also note that on the one hand I have code in my `RegitrationController` that, e.g., hashes the user password before saving it to the database. On the other hand this is achieved by a `UserDataPersister` on the API side.

What is the good practice to factorize that code and structure my architecture in order to be able to create users from both the form and the API? (I would like to keep the cool things that the Symfony `AbstractController` provides like `createForm`, `handleRequest`, `renderForm`, etc.)

I cannot find examples using both Form/Controller and **API Plateform**.

Is it a bad idea to have the Form/Controller and API in the same project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to switching to API Platform, you first have to unlearn what you have learned with more traditional apps :)

Things like creating/rendering forms, and handing requests, are possible, BUT keep in mind that your API accepts, among others, the `application/json` and not the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

It all really depends on your choice of client-side code. If you stick to more traditional forms with no `React`, `Angular`, or `Vue`, you send the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and your API Platform needs a way to denormalize that.

There is an official article on that topic: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/form-data/, but it has its own perks (such as CSRF handling)

A more common approach is to create a form entirely from scratch using some modern JS framework and just submit the object (in JSON format)

Comment: Indeed, I would like to avoid using frontend frameworks like React for this project.
Then, if I want to stick with the nice Symfony features to render forms/handle requests, I have to duplicate my code logic in the controller (for form) and in the data persister (for API). This does not seem to be a good practice, does it?

Answer (score 0):

i think it could be done by using Form instance as [DTO](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/) and feeding it into [State processor](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/state-processors/) with a validator, like in this [Validating delete operations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/validation/#validating-delete-operations) example. however, i am not sure it will work out of the box with the [ApiPlatform validator](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/3.1/src/Symfony/Validator/Validator.php). writing a custom one which handles Form properly could be required.